# Effect of "new" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, new-operator

I have written some code I found in a video, and it looks something like this:

```
var clientX = clientX || {} ; 
clientX.MyClass = function(initialValue){
  var var1 = initialValue;
  var publicMembers = {
    get_var1 : function(){
      return var1; 
    }
  };
  return publicMembers;
}



var result = new clientX.MyClass("val1");
alert(result.get_var1());

clientX.instance = new  clientX.MyClass("val2");
alert(clientX.instance.get_var1());


clientX.instance2= new clientX.MyClass("val3");
alert(clientX.instance2.get_var1());
```

The thing is, after deleting the "new" keyword when I use : `var result = new clientX.MyClass("val1");` Nothing is changed, so why the author chose to use it? What's the effect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript)

Answer (score 5):

The `MyClass` function makes no use of `this` and has an explicit `return` value, so the use of `new` has no practical effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

the new keyword is used as a piece of [pseudoclassical instantiation](http://tylermcginnis.com/object-creation-in-javascript-functional-instantiation-vs-prototypal-instantiation-vs-pseudo-classical-instantiation/), wherein a constructor object has properties attached to the keyword "this" but no return value is ever written.

```
var Car = function(){

  this.color = 'blue';
  this.make = 'toyota';
  this.model = 'camry';

}
```

now, writing var x = new Car() will add the following lines to the interpretation:

```
var Car = function(){
  var this = {}; //added by new
  this.color = 'blue';
  this.make = 'toyota';
  this.model = 'camry';
  return this; //added by new
}
```